# Fetch data in database and merge duplicate data

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I want to fetch data from the database using `CodeIgniter`.

```
function fetch_chapter() 
{
      $this->db->select('*');
      $this->db->from("chapter");
      $this->db->join('unit', 'unit.unit_number = chapter.unit_number', 'left');
      $this->db->order_by('chapter.unit_number', 'ASC');
      $this->db->order_by('chapter_number', 'ASC');
      $query = $this->db->get();
      return $query;        
}
```

I want result like following:

```
Unit 1
  Chapter 1
     Lesson 1
     Lesson 2
  Chapter 2
     Lesson 1
Unit 2
  Chapter 1
     Lesson 1
  Chapter 2
     Lesson 1
```

Comment: $this->db->distinct( ); use this line

Comment: $this->db->group_by("column_name");

Comment: when I use group_by it only return 1 chapter in each unit.

Comment: Your question Needs More Focus (it's Too Broad). Notice how you are asking for help with your model, then in comments, you need help with your contoller.  This is a type of scenario that volunteers don't like to get sucked into because it is "the question that never ends" aka "please write me a complete tutorial".

Answer (score 0):

May be this your controller code:

```
$this->load->model('modelname');
$data['s'] =  $this->modelname->fetch_chapter();
$this->load->view('foldername/filename', $data, FALSE);
```

Your model code:

```
function fetch_chapter() 
    {
          $this->db->select('*');
          $this->db->distinct( ); 
          $this->db->from("chapter");
          $this->db->join('unit', 'unit.unit_number = chapter.unit_number', 'left');
          $this->db->order_by('chapter.unit_number', 'ASC');
          $this->db->order_by('chapter_number', 'ASC');
          $query = $this->db->get();
          return $query->row();        
    }
```

your view page code in each text box:

```
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $s->fieldname; ?>" >
```

Comment: you have fetching bulk data or single row

Comment: you have to say full  problem with your model code i can't help you

Comment: there is no error.. the output  is Unit 1 chapter 1 Unit 1 Chapter 2 Unit 2 Chapter 1 Unit 2 Chapter 2.. unit is still repeated.